# C# adding row to table in word document dynamically

Tags: c#, office-interop, office-2007

I'm trying to fill a word document based on a template in C#.
I'm using bookmarks to mark the beginning of a table

```
Bookmark b = oWordDoc.Bookmarks["Bugs_Start"];

Word.Range range = b.Range; // = oWordDoc.Range(ref oBookmarkStart, ref oBookmarkEnd);
object unit = WdUnits.wdCell;
object count = 1;
while (dataExist)
{
range.InsertAfter("cell text");                
    range = range.Next(ref unit, ref count);

    range.InsertAfter("cell text");                
    range = range.Next(ref unit, ref count);
}
```

the template has only 3 rows in the table and sometime i need to add more rows to the table. How can I add more rows while i'm in the while loop?

If someone has a better idea of how to do it I will be glad to see a better way to implement this.
Thanks.

Comment: I got the table from the range (Word.Table table = range.Tables[1];) and added the rows before starting to go over the table.

Answer (score -1):

Without being facetious, have you actually tried just going ahead and moving to the next cell to insert with your code? Like in Word itself, it might automatically add another row for you. If not, then it would be helpful if you could access the table itself, since then you could use the table's Rows.Add method to add another row.

Comment: I did, but if there is no next cell I get null.

Comment: @JTeagle, your suggestion is based on speculation, and does not yield a valid solution to the OP's problem.